# Background not fitting in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm making a home page for my first website,

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Home Page </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css">
    </head>
    <body id = "Welcome">
        <div id = "Form"> 
            <h1> Pokémon Paradise </h1>
            <h1> Gotta Catch 'Em All </h1>
            <h2> Create an account now </h2>
            <button> Register </button>
            <h2> Already a member? </h2>
            <button> Login </button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <style>
    html {
        background-image: url(Background.png);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #Welcome {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 280px;
        margin-top: 130px;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Lucida Console";
        text-align: center;
    }
    button {
        border-radius: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        width: 80px;
        height: 30px;
    </style>
</html>
```

Here's the actual image [Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnH03.jpg)
And how it looks on my website [Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tBGh.jpg)
For the home page, the image gets cut off from the bottom. I'm not sure why.
If you run it on your PC, it might look different, first website, hasn't made it responsive. Also, since it's my first website, a suggestion would be nice, to make the home page more appealing.

Comment: Oh, my bad, my question is why does the image not fit for my website

Comment: I did add it. My bad

Comment: Can you provide the Main.css you are importing?

Comment: It is the style I added to the bottom

Comment: For me, the background image fully covers the screen.. Tested using Firefox Nightly, Chrome and Edge.

Comment: That's odd, I will try it on other devices and check my settings for the browser

Comment: Nice picture  anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {     
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

And put CSS codes in `<style> codes.. </style>` not `<script></script>`

Comment: Oh my bad, your suggestion did not work, might just be an issue on my side. I had it as a separate file, script was an accident.

Comment: The problem may be that the way you display the codes is different from what you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

You put your CSS into a `<script>` tag..

change the `<script>` to `<style> ... </style>` and you will be fine. Also put the styles into the head of the document.

Comment: It was another file, I just added it to here for convenience, not the issue, my bad though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `aspect-ratio` and show the entire image, you would have to set `background-color: black;`. In order to also prevent the bottom from cutting off, the best solution is `background-size: contain;`. I would also suggest positioning the image to the right side (`background-position: right center;`).Finally you give it the property `background-attachment: fixed;`.

Some suggestions: Use `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Should probaly also use `<form></form>` instead of `<div id="Form">`.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css" />
    </head>
    <body id="Welcome">
        <div id="Form">
            <h1>Pokémon Paradise</h1>
            <h1>Gotta Catch 'Em All</h1>
            <h2>Create an account now</h2>
            <button>Register</button>
            <h2>Already a member?</h2>
            <button>Login</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <style>
        html {
            background-image: url(Background.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: right center;
            background-size: contain;
            background-color: black;
        }
        #Welcome {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 280px;
            margin-top: 130px;
            color: white;
            font-family: "Lucida Console";
            text-align: center;
        }
        button {
            border-radius: 8px;
            border-style: solid;
            width: 80px;
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</html>
```